# example in measure theory that I am not understanding

Tags: measure-theory

This example presented by the book I don't understand how did they get that lim $A_n$ = 0. I understand why the limit exist since we have $(....A4 \subset A3 \subset A2 \subset A1)$ and hence the limit exists since the sequence of sets are non-decreasing and will be equal to $\cap A_n$, however $\cap A_n$ will be not equal to zero the example that I have in my head is

$A_1 = {1,2,3,4,....}$
$A_2 = {2,3,4,5....}$
$A_3 = {3,4,5,.....}$

So as we can see $\cap A_n$ will be nonzero it so I don't understand how did they reach this conclusion..?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\bigcap_{n \geq 1} A_n = \emptyset$. If you take any natural number $k$, the number will not be in $A_n$ for $n > k$.

Comment: I understand if we have for any n > k it won't be there but how does that relate to my question above ? maybe I am confused a little bit on the question would be nice if you clarify..

Comment: @KarimMansour I thought you asked why the intersection is empty. Did you ask about something else? Or wasn't my answer clear enough?

Comment: Or you didn't exactly ask that. You claimed that the intersection was non-empty, but I just proved that it is empty. Do you understand why it is empty?

Comment: Oh I see I understood it now after carefully looking thank you!